# Finding the stack 'tipping point' in F#

Tags: f#, limit, stack-overflow

Let's say I have a recursive function f(x) of the type int -> int.
It is expected that the greater x is, the more recursive calls f(x) will perform.

Given an infinite sequence of integers in an increasing order, I'm interested in the first integer in the sequence that will cause a StackOverflowException when using f on it.

How can I do that?

So far, I've tried making a simple function that just tests whether a StackOverflowException has been thrown when using a given function on a given integer. It looks like this:

```
let overflows f x = 
    try 
        ignore (f x) in false
    with
        | :? System.StackOverflowException -> true
```

However, it seems that it can't catch the StackOverflowException when it is thrown, even though that was the intention.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Big problem - this will depend on how many stack frames there are above the function call.  Why do you want to know this?

Comment: I have several recursive functions that I want to compare to see how well each one makes use of the stack. Basically, to see which one can handle the greatest input.

Comment: Could you modify your recursive functions to also return a stacktrace using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx ?

Comment: Hmm... Maybe, except I haven't used the StackTrace class before, so I have no clue yet how to do so... :-S

Comment: Just add a `(new StackTrace()).FrameCount` as an additional member to what you return

Comment: If you use tail recursion you avoid the problem of stack overflows. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Basic_Concepts#Recursion_or_Loops.3F

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 2.0 and above, it isn't possible to catch a `StackOverflowException` -- the process will just be terminated:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx

If you're only doing this to test the functions, there's a simpler way to get the information you want: write a bit of code which writes a counter (or even just a newline) to a text file, and call it at each iteration. Make sure you call `.Flush()` on the TextWriter (or whatever) each time you write to the file, so the data is actually written and not just buffered. When you run the program, it'll crash (as expected), but the number of lines in the file will be the same as the number of iterations the function performed before crashing.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.EnsureSufficientExecutionStack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.ensuresufficientexecutionstack.aspx), which throws a catchable [`InsufficientExecutionStackException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.insufficientexecutionstackexception.aspx) if you've almost used up all the stack.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to catching the `StackOverflowException` is to return `(new StackTrace()).FrameCount` which measures the current number of stack frames.

Care must be taken to ensure that there are the same number of overhead frames when comparing methods.  In particular, lambda expressions `fun ...` will each add a stack frame.